# Deploying OctoberCMS using AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, octobercms

I am setting up a new server for my OctoberCMS Application. I got to know about Elastic Beanstalk as a service which is really useful for deployment .
I have deployed a laravel application on the server using the Elastic Beanstalk Guide which worked fine.
But what about deploying October CMS .

I tried some deployment but I am really confused what to do about the public directory as all files are uploaded over there.
Any help is appreciated.